# Audio iPad app works in 6.1 simulator, but not on iPad

Tags: ipad, audio, ios-simulator

I’m writing an iPad audio app that requires the microphone - iOS7 and Xcode 5.  The app works in the simulator but not when running on the iPad 2 in either native mode, i.e. when launched from the iPad, or in debug mode when launched on the iPad from Xcode.  I’ve implemented the “request to use the microphone” code, and when I reset locations and privacy on the iPad, I am prompted to give permission. This all looks good.

My callback gets called as expected (again, running on the iPad), however when I look at the input buffer (provided by AudioUnitRender) it’s all zeros as though the mic weren’t working.  The mic on my iPad works for FaceTime and other audio input apps.  I’ve configured for 16-bit 2-channel LPCM.  Anybody have an idea what I’m overlooking?  I’ll supply any code you’d like to see.

Answer (score 0):

I was porting some code that was working fine on devices up to iOS6, but it wasn't detecting the mic on an iOS8 device.
After doing this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/ I realised that what was missing was setting up an audio session:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

This worked for me.
Hope this helps someone.